# Screen hierarchy in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing a C# form based application and was wondering how the screen hierarchy is laid out and what components are used.

The application flow is very much like a mobile app structure with one main window and from this you may drill down into different 'screen-stacks'.

What is the best way of doing this is C#? 
Do I use different forms or is form the base screen, and then only replace panels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use different forms or panels as it will most likely turn the code into a big unmaintanable ball of mud.

Instead you could look at using UserControls and dynamically load whichever is the most appropriate. This solution will work with a small number of controls however will get out of hand when there are many events, complex logic and maintaining state and I wouldn't imagine it would be that useful for anything other than small projects.

In 2005 the Patterns & Practices group implement the [Composite UI Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648747.aspx) as a first attempt at improving dynamically loaded user controls. However this was largely abandoned after the release of .NET 3 with Prisim. In November 2010 [Prisim 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx) was released in an effort to be more of an RIA a style architecture. Personally I would go with the Prisim approach as there is a good community, support from Microsoft and a lot of hard work has gone into the project to overcome the issues which you will undoubtably encounter.

Answer (score 0):

There are many varied ways to implement the UIX and workflow as described, each has their own strength and weaknesses that will become apparent the more you are exposed to a variety of different development scenarios.

You can use new Forms to expose the UI controls and functionality (this is not my preferred method), there are also a [variety of options for creating Custom Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171725.aspx) that would most likely be suitable for your application.

My preference would be towards creating composite controls for each UI component and handling the workflow itself using WorkFlow Foundation.

For the management of workflow Microsoft have the [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328), an extensible and flexible framework for implementing logical process flows within code, declaritively and programatically.

[Developing Custom Windows Forms Controls with the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hws6h2t.aspx)
[Walkthrough: Authoring a Composite Control with Visual C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)